# How do High and Low Pass Filters function

Tags: low-pass, high-pass-filter

I dont understand how Low Pass Filters function .Like when the Frequency is very small the capacitor behaves Like an Open circuit . And when the Frequency is very big the capacitor behaves Like a short circuit .so in all this Definitions the point is that the filter Always behaves like a high pass Filter . I need help to get this clarified . 
Im of course speaking about 1 Order Filters composed of a capacitor and a resistor.

Comment: Text text text, some more text, teeeext <-- This is text. If it was a schematic it would make more sense. Then we could all agree on what that text meant.

Comment: There are thousands of detailed explanations of this, for every level of detail. You haven't even drawn how you think the components are connected. Impossible to explain more, I think.

Comment: *the point is that the filter Always behaves like a high pass Filter* No, you describe that the **impedance** of a **capacitor** is inversely proportional (like 1/x) with the frequency. **Which is true**. But that does not make a filter yet. A filter consists of at least 2 components. One of those could be a capacitor.

Comment: You have described two opposite behaviors and concluded *"so in all this Definitions the point is that the filter Always behaves like a high pass Filter"* - how is that?

Answer (score 4):

A low pass filter on the left, a high pass filter on the right

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f43MIK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each has a -3dB, or corner, frequency of around 1600Hz. This will fall with larger components, rise with smaller ones.

Comment: You supplied the OP's missing schematic!

Comment: I borrowed your image for my answer to expand on why this works but +1.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases, the filter is a voltage divider between input and output, and its gain comes from the ratio of the two impedances.

Since only the capacitor's impedance changes with frequency, and always decreases with frequency, you can change the way the ratio varies with frequency by simply swapping the components.

One way round, high frequencies are passed, the other way round, they are diverted to ground and lost.

Answer (score 1):

The capacitor can be connected in series or in parallel. If the capacitor is in series the lower the frequency the higher the attenuation. If it is in parallel is the other way, because a low impedance will shunt the output.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider the filter on the left (and Thanks @Neil_UK for creating the image) this is a classic low pass filter. At low frequencies \$C_1\$ is a high impedance a relatively speaking \$R_1\$ a  much lower one so low frequencies can pass through easily without significant attenuation. At high frequencies \$C_1\$ is a low impedance a relatively speaking \$R_1\$ a  much higher one so high frequencies can not pass through easily and are significantly attenuated.

The corner point in the filter will be when \$X_{C1} = R_1\$.

I won't explain the filter on the right but it is a classic high pass filter and you should be able to use a similar argument to see why.

---

Consider the low pass filter on the left hat at low enough frequencies C1 is almost an open circuit so  has a resistance much higher R1 has little attenuation. At high enough frequencies C1 has very low resistance so does lots of attenuation.

Lets put some detail on this as the simple appeal general principles does not seem to be working.

We can think of this as a simple potential divider but we have we have to use complex numbers.

$$A = \dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \dfrac{Z_{C1}}{Z_{R1}+Z_{C1}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{j \cdot \omega \cdot C1}}{R1 + \dfrac{1}{j \cdot \omega \cdot C1}}= \dfrac{1}{1 + j \cdot \omega \cdot C1 \cdot R1}$$

Comment: Hi " At low frequencies C1 is a high impedance a relatively speaking R1 a much lower one so low frequencies can pass through easily without significant attenuation" so they are not significantly attenuated by the resistor but the capacitor C1 on the other hand is a high impendance so low frequency do get attenuated significantly by the capacitor ? in low pass filters and this is exactly the point that I dont understand

Comment: I've edited this to try and clarify.